# Thread freezing the application

Tags: .net, multithreading, visual-c++, c++-cli, vtk

I'm designing an application which reads [DICOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM) data sets and visualizes them with volume rendering techniques by using [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) library. Anyway, the problem I'm dealing is volume rendering is really CPU-bounded process. If I handle the volume rendering in a single threaded process, application (GUI) freezes and passes to "not responding" state. I have written another thread for volume rendering process. However GUI still freezes, here are the codes.

```
private: System::Void volumeRenderButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             volumeRenderThread = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this, &Form1::volumeRender));
             volumeRenderThread->Priority = System::Threading::ThreadPriority::Lowest;
             volumeRenderThread->Start();                                   
         }

private: void volumeRender()
         {
             threeDPictureBox->Invoke(gcnew volumeDelegate(this, &Form1::volumeDelegateMethod));        

             /*
             if ( threeDPictureBox->InvokeRequired )
             {
                threeDPictureBox->Invoke(gcnew System::Action(this, &Form1::volumeRender));
             }
             else
             {
                 dicom->VolumeRender(threeDPictureBox, vrSettings); 
             }
             */
         }
private: delegate void volumeDelegate();

private: void volumeDelegateMethod()
         {
             dicom->VolumeRender(threeDPictureBox, vrSettings); 
         }


void Dicom::VolumeRender( Windows::Forms::PictureBox ^pictureBox, VRsettings *settings )
{
    renderer = vtkSmartPointer < vtkRenderer > :: New();
    renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer < vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow > :: New();
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
    renderWindow->SetParentId((HWND)((pictureBox->Handle).ToPointer()));
    renderWindow->SetSize(pictureBox->Width, pictureBox->Height);
    renderWindow->Initialize();
    /* A lot of stuff here */
    ...
    ...
    renderWindow->Render();
    iren->Initialize();     // vtkWin32RenderWindowInteractor

}
```

threeDPictureBox is a PictureBox component that I'm sending it to volumeRender method of dicom object. vrSettings is a struct for volume Rendering parameters. 
When the volume Render button is clicked and click event handler fired, volumeRenderThread starts and freezes the application even I have set its priority Lowest! I have also tried the lines which is commented. None of them works. What's the point I'm missing?? Thanks for answers from now!!

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning for this line `threeDPictureBox->Invoke(gcnew volumeDelegate(this, &Form1::volumeDelegateMethod));`? Why not to call `Dicom::VolumeRenderer` directly? (I suspect the answer to that but I want to be sure)

Comment: Just because .NET does not allow cross-thread operation.

Answer (score 1):

You are just passing a delegate that does the actual work back to your UI thread to execute with that call to `Invoke` so setting the priority of `volumeRenderThread` doesn't help any.

You need to move as much of the actual work out of the UI thread as possible. Your snip only says `/* A lot of stuff here */` so it's hard to suggest exactly how you should go about separating most of the work from the stuff that must be run on the UI thread, but that's what you'll need to do.

Comment: The code I've snipped is completely related with vtk Objects. The only thing is related with UI is setting parent ID of renderWindow.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that all this time taken is *just* rendering and nothing else. And you can render onto UI only from the UI thread. I think the solution should be library specific. I'd look for topics that discuss usage of this library for rendering from a .NET app.

Answer (score 1):

Your thread is invoked on a method that immediately jumps back onto the UI thread.

In other words, it has one action: tell the UI Thread to do the work.

Comment: When I'm not invoking the threeDPictureBox, I'm getting the "cross thread operation not valid" runtime error. Then how to manage it??

Comment: That's because whenever you mess with the UI, you need to be on the UI thread. However, you should do everything _except_ modify threeDPictureBox _before_ calling Invoke. That way, when you're ready to Invoke, all of the work is done.

Comment: Yes, I know, but rendering process needs the HANDLE pointer of threeDPictureBox before rendering starts. It's a real problem

Comment: On what line do you get "cross thread operation not valid"? is VTK throwing this?

Comment: If I directly call dicom->VolumeRender method without invoking threeDPictureBox. It gives while trying to setparentID line executing

Comment: I agree with zerspri, this is very library specific. Still, I imagine you can probably set the PictureBox to double buffer (`box->DoubleBuffer = true;`) and simply work on the back buffer in a background thread (any random Bitmap will do). That way you only block when you're copying over the buffer and that should be a pretty speedy process.

Comment: And it is not VTK related. .NET does not allow GUI components to be reached by another threads

Comment: Correct, but the usage of VTK on the other hand is. I have never used it.

Comment: By the way PictureBox does not have DoubleBuffer property, I've tried to set DoubleBuffered property, but it gives that error "System::Windows::Forms::Control::DoubleBuffered::set': candidate function(s) not accessible"

Comment: @anarhikos I had forgotten that it was [`protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered.aspx). You'll have to extend it to user that property of it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following and let me know if it works. My C++ is quite rusty, but the idea is the following. I'm guessing that VTK only needs HWND to do the its job, so you need to retrieve HWND in your UI thread and then pass this to VTK.

Change you code like this (make sure to change my C#isms if any to proper C++):

```
private: System::Void volumeRenderButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    volumeRenderThread = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ParameterizedThreadStart(this, &Form1::volumeRender));
    volumeRenderThread->Priority = System::Threading::ThreadPriority::Lowest;
    volumeRenderThread->Start(pictureBox->Handle);                                   
}

private: void volumeRender(System::Object^  pictureBox)
{
    dicom->VolumeRender((HWND)((System::IntPtr)pictureBox).ToPointer()), vrSettings); 
}

void Dicom::VolumeRender( HWND pictureBox, VRsettings *settings )
{
    renderer = vtkSmartPointer < vtkRenderer > :: New();
    renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer < vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow > :: New();
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
    renderWindow->SetParentId(pictureBox);
    renderWindow->SetSize(pictureBox->Width, pictureBox->Height);
    renderWindow->Initialize();
    /* A lot of stuff here */
    ...
    ...
    renderWindow->Render();
    iren->Initialize();     // vtkWin32RenderWindowInteractor
}
```

Comment: I've tried, Two compile errors: error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'System::Object ^' to 'HWND' and Error 4 error C2664: 'void System::Threading::Thread::Start(System::Object ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void *' to 'System::Object ^'

Comment: Yep, you need to resolved these casting issues, the way c++ supposed to deal with them. If you know c++ CLI well this should not be difficult. Good luck.

Comment: @anarhikos: I updated the code a little. Was passing the hwnd parameter in a wrong place. Have a look now.

Comment: I know, I've passed it with Start, Howver casting to object ^ to void * seems little bit problematic. Casting does not work

Comment: I did it =) no compile error, worked GUI not freezed while rendering but the pitcureBox didnt show the rendered picture. Something wrongs again

Comment: Now you need a VTK expert. I think we did all we could in .NET land. If your freezing problem is solved you may consider accepting my answer and opening a new question that provides more details about your VTK rendering, so someone familiar with VTK could help you.

Comment: Yes, you're right. We have stucked now in VTK. Really thanks for your help. Yes freezing problem is solved, I will if I cant do it my own

Comment: The casts you need were originally in this line: `renderWindow->SetParentId((HWND)((pictureBox->Handle).ToPointer()));`.  I think what you need now is the signature `void volumeRender(System::IntPtr  pictureBoxHandle)` and go from there.

Comment: I've tried, not works, when debugging after renderWindow->Render, it really renders and successfully binds with threeDPictureBox, however as soon as rendering thread finishing, threeDpictureBox turns white. Problem is completely related with .NET