# Updating a Windows Form component with its Handle outside of main UI thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading, c++-cli

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026126/thread-freezing-the-application%20%22%22) about my problem, and I've made some progress. I'm sending the Handle of a PictureBox component to my VolumeRender method, VolumeRender method binds the PictureBox component  with vtkRenderWindow, process the pipeline and update the renderWindow. Okay, this process is done outside of UI thread but the problem is, as soon as volume rendering thread is out of scope, UI thread I don't know why but it frees the pictureBox component. Here are the codes;

```
private: System::Void volumeRenderButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    volumeRenderThread = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(
        gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this, &Form1::volumeRender));
        volumeRenderThread->Start(threeDPictureBox->Handle);
}

private: void volumeRender( System::Object ^obj )
{               
     IntPtr ^ptr = (IntPtr ^) obj;
     dicom->VolumeRender((HWND)(ptr->ToPointer()), vrSettings);     
}

void Dicom::VolumeRender(HWND pictureBoxHandle, VRsettings *settings )
{
    renderer = vtkSmartPointer < vtkRenderer > :: New();
    renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer < vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow > :: New();
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
    renderWindow->SetParentId(pictureBoxHandle);
    renderWindow->SetSize(settings->width, settings->height);
    renderWindow->Initialize();

    iren = vtkSmartPointer < vtkWin32RenderWindowInteractor > :: New();
    iren->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

    /* Volume Render Pipeline 
    ...
    ...
    */

    renderWindow->Render();
    iren->Initialize();
}
```

I'm sure that the problem is not VTK related. When debugging the code, after the execution renderWindow->Render() statement, in the main form, rendered image is seen on pictureBox Component, but after the volumeRender thread is out of scope, threeDPictureBox is somehow freed. Thanks for answers! really need help

Comment: VTK docs are not great.  But they don't mention anywhere that it supports rendering from another thread.  Which means it doesn't.

Comment: Do you think the problem is VTK related? I'm not good at .NET framework, Am I doing the right thing at .NET side?

Comment: No, it's your code.  You cannot use a thread to render.

Comment: Do I have to render it on main thread to freeze the application ? It's a bad idea

Comment: Render to a buffer, then send the buffer to the main thread.